# How to add ant as dependency to a Jenkins plugin?

Tags: maven, jenkins, ant

I have added the following dependency to a Jenkins plugin

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ant/ant -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I get the following error whenI do `mvn hpi:run`

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.2.jenkins-1:enforce (display-info) @ osf-builder-suite-for-sfcc-deploy ---
[INFO] Restricted to JDK 1.7 yet org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.10.1:compile contains org/apache/tools/ant/AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.class targeted to JDK 1.8
[INFO] Restricted to JDK 1.7 yet org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.10.1:compile contains org/apache/tools/ant/launch/AntMain.class targeted to JDK 1.8
```

Any idea what's going on and what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting 1.10.0, Ant requires Java 8, while your project is apparently restricted to compile up to JDK 7 (Maven detects this incompatibility via the maven-enforcer-plugin. From this [release note](https://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/RELEASE-NOTES-1.10.0.html):

> Ant 1.10.x requires Java8 or newer at compile or build time.
>
> The 1.9.x series wil stay compatible with Java5.

Switching to a 1.9.x version should solve the error.